# front/back (duplex) printing in reportviewer

Tags: pdf, printing, report, reportviewer

My report generates phone bills to over 1000 different clients. I created a single PDF with all the bills, to make print easier for the user, but if the current bill ends in a number that is odd it'll begin printing on the back side of the last page of the previous client.

I need to insert an extra page break (blank page) if the current page number is odd. But I'm have some trouble to find out how and where should I test it and How to fix this.

Any ideas?

Comment: when you create phone bills, before to join all these single pdf files **(1 pdf = 1 phone bill = related to only 1 client)**, do you store these somewhere? if yes, you can apply my workaround before to join all pdf together into one multipage pdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820830/how-to-merge-pdf-filesor-ps-if-not-possible-such-that-every-file-will-begin-in/9827598#9827598

Comment: Thanks @Dingo gonna take a look at it.