# Insert a blank page after each file/record while merging using pdftk

Tags: pdf, merge, pdftk

I have a job which creates N pdf files in a folder, I am merging these files using pdftk. Usually each pdf file is of two pages.but the problem is, sometimes the pdf may get to 3 pages, so i need to insert a blank page after each pdf, so that i can differentiate them.

is there any a way to achieve this.

currently i am using the folowing script to merge pdfs.

`

```
@echo off

pdftk *.pdf cat output Avinash.pdf
ren Avinash.pdf Avinash.doc
del *.pdf
ren Avinash.doc Avinash.pdf
```

`

Comment: Do you want to insert a blank page after every pdf or just after the 3 pages ones?

Comment: actually its like i want to start next pdf only in odd numbers say1,5,9,21 etc etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge PDF files (or PS if not possible) such that every file will begin in a odd page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820830/how-can-i-merge-pdf-files-or-ps-if-not-possible-such-that-every-file-will-begi)

Comment: You might also try solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082188/how-to-concatenate-multiple-pdf-as-one-each-input-pdf-starting-on-an-even-page